# Reading files in 64kb blocks

Tags: c, file, io

I want to create a function that Copies a file to some location. I'm wondering weather it would be beneficial to read it in in 64kb blocks? Or should I just dynamically allocate the buffer? Or should I just use the system() function to do it on the command line?

I mean like this:

```
int copy_file(const char *source, const char *dest)
{
    FILE *fsource, *fdest;
    int readSize;
    unsigned char buffer[64*1024]; //64kb in size

    fsource = fopen(source, "rb");
    fdest = fopen(dest, "wb");
    if(!fsource)
        return 0;
    if(!fdest)
    {
        fclose(fsource);
        return 0;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        readSize = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fsource);
        if(!readSize)
            break;
        fwrite(buffer, 1, readSize, fdest);
    }

    fclose(fsource);
    fclose(fdest);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: intuitively, definitely not the system() from command line. It will take in the overhead of sending that command, then the operations, then getting back to your original program.

Comment: Please add error checking to both `fwrite` and `fclose` (at least the one for the output file), or you'll get silently failing copies which is really bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal read size is going to be very platform dependent. A power of 2 is definitely a good idea, but without testing, it would be hard to say which size would be best.

If you want to see how cp copies files, you can see the [bleeding edge source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cp.c)